# how to type and mark a tabulation in a textbox control C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, focus

I need to enter a text to be inserted in a MySQL database, this text always contains tabulation e.g "/t"
When I type the Tab key, another control in the same form will take the focus
I there a way to disable this behavior programaticaly  in C# language , so I could mark the tabulation inside the text 
Thanks.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, Silverlight ... ?

Comment: I assumed you were doing it on web and my answer work for that, let me know if its not web,

Comment: Yes,, I want to create an offline website generator, I don't want to use any existent CMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you need to accomplish this in a WindowsForms application to both implement the following method in your Form:

> ```
>     protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
>     {
>         if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
>         {
>             textBox1.Text += "\t";
>             // Set the selection on the end of text.
>             textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
>             textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
>             return true;
>         }
> ```

```
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: this almost work , the tabulation is marked but not always inn the right line of text

Comment: I'm changed the code, see this. If works please vote up and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check the following solution http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/ViewA94BBC8A-8DC4-4F14-98F9-DEDFCF40DA07.htm

Although it is just for IE but it will give you the idea about what you haev to do

Comment: I do not need a non C# solution! I need to enter a text that have tabulationn inside it so that text will be next insertted in a MySQL database WINFORMS Application not web. my application will finally generate .html files

Comment: Ok then i think julio solution with minor tweak is fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript for this

```
    textarea.observe('keydown', function (e) {
  if(e.keyCode==9) {
    e.element().insert("\t");
    e.stop();
  }
}
```

here is also more information about it :

http://ajaxian.com/archives/handling-tabs-in-textareas

Comment: I do not need a non C# solution! I need to enter a text that have tabulationn inside it so that text will be next insertted in a MySQL database WINFORMS Application not web. my application will finally generate .html files

Comment: If you dont say its a WINFORMS we cant know that, it cant be done in c# if its a web project.